# Want to change affiliate tag to salesman in opencart

Tags: opencart

I want to change affiliate tag name into salesman from the dashboard. in Sales->Affiliates.
and in their form also of backend. Just change the text of affiliate into sales man . From where i have to change this.

Comment: If using a ready-to-use theme or custom theme, take a look at any language file it might included with it. And to add to `Chetan` answer, take a look and edit the necessary files inside the `catalog/language/english/affiliate`. In the `Default` theme, you may find this `$_['heading_title'] = 'My Affiliate Account';` from `account.php` file. Changing this text will change the text from the Affiliate's Header Page.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit language files

for e.g. open `catalog/language/english/affiliate/login.php` and replace word affiliate with whatever word you want. I guess you will have to edit all files in this affiliate folder.

similarly find relevant files in `admin/language/english/` directory

Note : don't change the file or folder name

Comment: @user3073151 there is no way it will not work, i just changed `Affiliate Program` to `X Program` in above mentioned login.php file and visited `yoursite/index.php?route=affiliate/login` and its changed.

Comment: @user3073151 if you are using any vqmods then clear your cache.